# g++ 5.3 expected initializer before <function>

Tags: c++, gcc

I understand that this error is typically a syntax problem. I've gone through this with a fine toothcomb and can't spot it. The example below is whittled  down to a couple of files which display the problem. The header files describe an API that is provided as a couple of lib files which I've referenced in the Eclipse project, but just trying to compile the following from the command line gives the same error.

I have several chained includes before getting to the first function declaration which throws an "expected initializer" error, along with every other declaration that follows.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include "defn.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

defn.h

```
#ifndef GEO_DEFINITIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define GEO_DEFINITIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define C_MICROSOFT
#define _UNICODE
#include "gxlib.h"

#endif // GEO_DEFINITIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

gxlib.h

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

#ifdef C_MICROSOFT

#define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __declspec(dllexport)
#define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
#define GX_WRAPPER_CALL  _cdecl
#define GX_STANDARD_CALL _stdcall

#define GX_OBJECT_PTR    void*

#define GX_VAR
#define GX_CONST         const

#define GX_VOID          void
#define GX_LONG          long
#define GX_DOUBLE        double
#define GX_HANDLE        long

#define GX_LONG_PTR      long*
#define GX_DOUBLE_PTR    double*
#define GX_HANDLE_PTR    long*
#define GX_ASTR_PTR      char*
#define GX_WSTR_PTR      wchar_t*
#if defined(GEO_UTF8)
   #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_ASTR_PTR
#elif defined( _UNICODE)
   #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_WSTR_PTR
#else
   #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_ASTR_PTR
#endif

#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif



/*---------------- Copy_3DN[_public] ----------------*/

GX_WRAPPER_FUNC GX_LONG GX_WRAPPER_CALL
Copy_3DN(GX_VAR   GX_OBJECT_PTR,
         GX_CONST GX_HANDLE_PTR,
         GX_CONST GX_HANDLE_PTR);


#ifdef __cplusplus
   }
#endif
```

The command line and exact error is

```
c:\Code\CPP>g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from defn.h:11:0,
                 from main.cpp:4:
gxlib.h:55:1: error: expected initializer before 'Copy_3DN'
 Copy_3DN(GX_VAR   GX_OBJECT_PTR,
```

As I mentioned above, this is just an excerpt from a larger project that I'm building in Eclipse Mars using the MinGW-64 5.3 toolchain. Within Eclipse I've defined all of the include files and linked to the libraries, but this simple commandline example with everything in the same directory demonstrates the error.

Comment: You also removed all the necessary parts that are needed to have a [mcve], in order to be able to answer the question.

Comment: How can we know unless seeing where `Copy_3DN` actually occurs?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Copy_3DN is defined in a library file. There's no code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've rejigged it above, so that it is in fact a complete program, and provided a little more background. The behavior is the same.

Comment: You appears to be trying to compile this code using gcc. The problem appears to be the headers referencing a non-standard "_cdecl" keyword, that gcc does not know about. This code uses Microsoft compiler-specific extension that are not supported by gcc.

Comment: aha.. that explains a lot. Now to find the workaround. I don't want to edit the headers, as they are provided by the vendor and updated regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lead to the answer by @SamVarshavchik's comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207170/which-gcc-distro-supports-declspecdllexport-cdecl-and-stdcall) thread. The problem is the MSVC specific syntax

```
#define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __declspec(dllexport)
#define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
#define GX_WRAPPER_CALL  _cdecl
#define GX_STANDARD_CALL _stdcall
```

In my case the MSVC definitions are wrapped within the C_MICROSOFT #ifdef block, and that is the ONLY occurence of that definition, so the simplest solution is to remove the C_MICROSOFT define in defn.h and replace it with:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __attribute__ ((dllexport))
    #define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
    #define GX_WRAPPER_CALL __attribute__((cdecl))
    #define GX_STANDARD_CALL __attribute__((stdcall))
    #define _stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))
    #define _cdecl __attribute__((cdecl))

    #define GX_OBJECT_PTR    void*

    #define GX_VAR
    #define GX_CONST         const

    #define GX_VOID          void
    #define GX_LONG          long
    #define GX_DOUBLE        double
    #define GX_HANDLE        long

    #define GX_LONG_PTR      long*
    #define GX_DOUBLE_PTR    double*
    #define GX_HANDLE_PTR    long*
    #define GX_ASTR_PTR      char*
    #define GX_WSTR_PTR      wchar_t*
    #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_WSTR_PTR
#else
    #define C_MICROSOFT
#endif
```