# which gcc distro supports __declspec(dllexport) _cdecl and _stdcall

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I am trying to get started using mingw (MinGW-w64) and eclipse after working in C++Builder for a long time. I'm very confused.

My work mostly revolves around a vendor supplied API which is MSVC-centric. It consists of 3 header files and a couple of libs. I was able to use their headers unchanged in C++Builder but am running into lots of problems with g++.

```
#define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __declspec(dllexport)
#define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
#define GX_WRAPPER_CALL  _cdecl
#define GX_STANDARD_CALL _stdcall


#define GX_OBJECT_PTR    void*

#define GX_VAR
#define GX_CONST         const

#define GX_VOID          void
#define GX_LONG          long
#define GX_DOUBLE        double
#define GX_HANDLE        long

#define GX_LONG_PTR      long*
#define GX_DOUBLE_PTR    double*
#define GX_HANDLE_PTR    long*
#define GX_ASTR_PTR      char*
#define GX_WSTR_PTR      wchar_t*
#if defined(GEO_UTF8)
   #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_ASTR_PTR
#elif defined( _UNICODE)
   #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_WSTR_PTR
#else
   #define GX_STR_PTR       GX_ASTR_PTR
#endif

#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif



/*---------------- Copy_3DN[_public] ----------------*/

GX_WRAPPER_FUNC GX_LONG GX_WRAPPER_CALL
Copy_3DN(GX_VAR   GX_OBJECT_PTR,
         GX_CONST GX_HANDLE_PTR,
         GX_CONST GX_HANDLE_PTR);
GX_STANDARD_FUNC GX_LONG GX_STANDARD_CALL
Std_Copy_3DN(GX_VAR   GX_OBJECT_PTR,
             GX_CONST GX_HANDLE_PTR,
             GX_CONST GX_HANDLE_PTR);
...hundreds more like this
```

This yields a whole bunch of "expected initializer before " errors.

I've had some success by redefining the first 4 defines like this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __attribute__ ((dllexport))
    #define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
    #define GX_WRAPPER_CALL
    #define GX_STANDARD_CALL

#else
    #define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __declspec(dllexport)
    #define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
    #define GX_WRAPPER_CALL  _cdecl
    #define GX_STANDARD_CALL _stdcall
#endif
```

but it barfs later on when it encounters

```
GX_WRAPPER_FUNC GX_LONG GX_WRAPPER_CALL
RegisterResourceTracking_GEO(GX_VAR   GX_OBJECT_PTR,
                             GX_CONST GX_LONG_PTR,
                             GX_OBJECT_PTR,
                             void (_stdcall *param3)(void*));
```

I would really like to use these headers WITHOUT editing them, and I've seen some references that suggest the correct choice of gcc distro might support  this syntax, but I've tried a number already with no luck. I've tried both the i686 and x86-64 variants of MinGW-w64 and Nuwen and TDM. I'm not concerned with cross platform issues as the host app is Windows only anyways, and for my own stubborn reasons I don't want to give up and switch to MSVC.

So, is there a gcc distro which will support this syntax? If not, what is the path of least resistance?

cheers

Comment: Have you tried `#define __stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))` ?

Comment: The single underscore version lost the battle, use two.  So __stdcall instead of _stdcall.

Comment: @BenVoigt that works. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can expand your set of macro definitions to cover the keywords gcc doesn't recognize:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define _cdecl __attribute__((cdecl))
    #define __cdecl __attribute__((cdecl))
    #define _stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))
    #define __stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))

    #define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __attribute__ ((dllexport))
#else
    #define GX_WRAPPER_FUNC  __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

As a bonus, those make the original definitions here work:

```
#define GX_STANDARD_FUNC
#define GX_WRAPPER_CALL  _cdecl
#define GX_STANDARD_CALL _stdcall
```

(FWIW, note that this is possible because most MSVC extensions are new simple keywords, from the space of identifiers reserved to the implementation.  gcc's multi-token `__attribute__(())` magic makes mapping in the reverse direction completely impossible.  So any time you write code using gcc non-portable features, hide them behind macros.)